# magento 2 how to call any block function in phtml

Tags: magento2, blocks, template

How can I call any block function in any phtml? For example if I want to call my custom block function in product list.phtml?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Try like this.

For ex your block class is

```
<?php
namespace Company\Helloworld\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Main extends Template
{
    public function getMyCustomMethod()
    {
        return '<b>I Am From MyCustomMethod</b>';
    }
}
```

then in any phtml file you can use following code to get method of this block.

```
<?php
$blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Company\Helloworld\Block\Main');
echo $blockObj->getMyCustomMethod();
?>
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 7):

If the template is linked to the block, for example:

```
<block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Name" name="name" template="Vendor_Module::name.phtml"/>
```

And you have a public method `myMethod()` defined in `Vendor\Module\Block\Name` you can call the following in `name.phtml` :

```
$block->myMethod();
```

Comment: @ Raphael  is it `$block->myMethod();` **OR**  `$this->myMethod();` ?

Comment: @AshishMadankar for Magento 1 it's `$this->myMethod()`, for Magento 2 it's `$block->myMethod()`

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism I want to call my custom block function in any phtml, basically my question is how can I create $myBlock object for any of my block.

Comment: You need to assign your block to the template.phtml in layout file. Then only you can call your own function in phtml.

Answer (score 1):

**Place following code in any phtml file:-**

```
<?php
$blockName = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\your_block_file_name');
?>
```

yourBlockFileMethodName(); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Place your block File in the root directory of your module /Block/Your_block_file.php(remember to user first capital Letter for folder and file).

App/Code/Your/Module/Block/Your_block_file.php

```
 <?php

namespace Your\Module\Block;

class Your_block_file extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry             $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory     $formFactory
     * @param array                                   $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get form action URL for POST booking request
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFormAction()
    {
        die('Hello World');
    }
}
```

Then link your block file with template in view/frontend/layout/your_file.xml file you defined the block file

App/Code/Your/Module/view/frontend/layout/your_file.xml(if you are using routes.xml make sure the name of your file must be like for ex. frontname_controllerFolder_FileUnderControlerFolder.xml)

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>{Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Your/Module/Block/Your_block_file" name="gridpage.form" template="Your_Module:: your_template.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then Define your template file in App/Code/Your/Module/view/frontend/templates/your_template.phtml

```
<?= $block->getFormAction(); ?>
```

Thats how you can call Block functions in in template file