# how to get block data on phtml template in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module, blocks, collection

what is missing in my code block data not shown in phtml template

block page

```
namespace xxxx\Trails\Block;

use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use \xxxx\Trails\Model\ResourceModel\Post\Collection as PostCollection;
use \xxx\Trails\Model\ResourceModel\Post\CollectionFactory as PostCollectionFactory;
use \xxx\Trails\Model\Post;

class Users extends Template
{
    /**
     * CollectionFactory
     * @var null|CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_postCollectionFactory = null;
    public $sortOrder = 0;
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PostCollectionFactory $postCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PostCollectionFactory $postCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_postCollectionFactory = $postCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->sortOrder = $this->getRequest()->getParam('sort');
    }

    /**
     * @return Post[]
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        /** @var PostCollection $postCollection */
//                $customerId=$this->getLayout()->createBlock('Scaledesk\Trails\Block\Session')->getCustomerId();

        $customerId=$this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();

//        var_dump($customerId);


        $postCollection = $this->_postCollectionFactory->create();
        $search = trim($this->getRequest()->getParam('search'));
        $sort = trim($this->getRequest()->getParam('sort'));
        $postCollection->addFieldToSelect('*');
        $postCollection->addFieldToFilter('main_table.entity_id',$customerId);
        $postCollection->getSelect()->join( array('customer_entity'=> $postCollection->getTable('customer_entity')), 'customer_entity.entity_id = main_table.entity_id');
        if($search != '') {
            $postCollection->addFieldToFilter('trails_name',
                array('like' => '%' . $search . '%'));
        }
        if ($sort != '') {

            // $postCollection->setOrder('created_at', ($sort==1 ? 'asc':'desc'));
            $postCollection->setOrder('trails_id', ($sort==1 ? 'asc':'desc'));

        }
//           var_dump($postCollection->getSelect()->__toString());
//        die();

        $postCollection->load();
        var_dump($postCollection->getItems()); die();
        return $postCollection->getItems();



    }

    /**
     * For a given post, returns its url
     * @param Post $post
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPostUrl(
        Post $post
    ) {
        return $this->getUrl().'trails/post/view/id/'. $post->getId();
    }




}
```

and phtml template

```
 <?php

//    var_dump(getUserAllTrails());
      var_dump($block->getUsers());

//    foreach ($block->getTrails() as $post){
//    echo $post->getTrailsName();
//    }
//
    ?>
```

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">


        <block class="xxx\Trails\Block\Users"
               name="post.users"
               template="xxx_Trails::post/trail.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

controller page

```
namespace xxx\Trails\Controller\Post;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use \Magento\Framework\Registry;


class Users extends Action
{
    const REGISTRY_KEY_POST_ID = 'xxxx_trails_trails_id';

    /**
     * Core registry
     * @var Registry
     *
     */
    protected $customerSession;


    protected $_coreRegistry;

    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     *
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $coreRegistry,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory





    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context
        );
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;



    }

    /**
     * Saves the blog id to the register and renders the page
     * @return Page
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */

    public function execute()
    {


        $blockInstance = $this->_objectManager->get('xxxx\Trails\Block\Users');
        $blockInstance->getUsers();

            $this->_coreRegistry->register(self::REGISTRY_KEY_POST_ID, (int)$this->_request->getParam('id'));
            $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
            return $resultPage;

    }
```

Comment: var_dump($postCollection->getItems()); die();
data are show

Comment: Can you share the xml code from where you are calling the phtml?

Comment: can you simply try with this code in your template file `var_dump($block->getUsers());`

Comment: are you sure your block is not being called from your template file..try to `die('test'');` in your block file.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121364/magento-2-how-to-call-any-block-function-in-phtml try this

Answer (score 0):

**You did the mistake. You can't render a block using below code from controller**

> ```
>     $blockInstance = $this->_objectManager->get('xxxx\Trails\Block\Users');
>     $blockInstance->getUsers()
> ```

first ,you need to call layout then render the block via layout file or code.

Comment: I want to print on a template or not on a controller.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if your **route** is **xxxx** and **controller file** name is **Index.php** and **method name** is **Index** then you need to create xxxx_index_index.xml file under this path xxxx\Trails\view\frontend\layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="xxxx\Trails\Block\Users" name="test-block" template="test.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Or you can call direct block in your file this way also

```
<?php
$blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('xxxx\Trails\Block\Users');
echo $blockObj->getUsers();
?>
```

Comment: I want to print on a template or not on a controller

Comment: <?php

      var_dump($block->getUsers());
    ?>   Phtml template

Comment: Above code for you can call block methods in phtml file.

Comment: on controller and block page  working  but  on a template  not working

Comment: array is empty on template

Comment: add session then not woking

Comment: try with simple string so you can get idea where issue is ? if you get string in phtml then issue in your function

Comment: before  session working  fine

Comment: its second issue so please create new questin for session issue.