# Magento 2: object manager construct call without calling direct in phtml file

Tags: magento2

I need to call object manager in my phtml file but I don't want to call direct in my file.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
```

Please suggest

Comment: create in your block file and get phtml file

Comment: create block or helper and call in phtml

Comment: Can you please share the code?

Comment: Follow this way : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/121391

Comment: Let me know if you'll face any issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create one common helper file in your custom module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Helper/Data.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $_objectManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
    }

    public function getObjectManager(){
        return $this->_objectManager;
    }
}
```

And then you can use `objectManager` in your `phtml` file using this line

```
<?php $objectManager = $this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\Data')->getObjectManager(); ?>
```

- You can create block file in your custom module directory here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/CustomBlock.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class CustomBlock extends Template
{
    protected $_objectmanager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager
    ){
        $this->_objectmanager = $objectmanager;
    }

    public function getObjectManager()
    {
        return $this->_objectmanager;
    }
}
```

Now you need to add this class in your layout xml file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\CustomBlock" name="mkt.form.jquery" template="Abc_Mkt::abc.phtml" /> 
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Here I've added custom block which we have created in custom module instead of using this `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` default Magento template Block.

Now you can use object manager using this line in your phtml file.

```
<?php $objectManager = $block->getObjectManager(); ?>
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I need to create block for this@kishan

Comment: No, You need to create one Helper file in your custom module, and you can use this anywhere in your phtml file

Comment: Yes i know, But want to create a block and not able to find

Comment: Where you want to create block ?

Comment: In my module@kishan

Comment: Okay means you want to access object manager from your custom block ? not using helper ? Right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101165/discussion-between-shiwani-and-kishan-savaliya).

Comment: Yes Exactly@kishan

Comment: Can I use the block in the model?@kishan

Comment: Am getting when i call in model --------------Invalid method Abc\Mkt\Model\Callback\Interceptor::helper @kishan

Answer (score 0):

Create Block File :

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Main extends Template
{
    protected $objectmanager;

    public function __construct(
        ..
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager
        ..
    ){
        $this->objectmanager = $objectmanager;
    }

    public function getObjManager()
    {
        return $this->objectmanager;
    }
}
```

Call block function in phtml file :

```
<?php
$blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Main')->getObjManager();
?>
```